# How to comment string starting with "//" this?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I am learning compiler construction these days, and I am having trouble while making the code for comment in it.
What is actually happening is that when ever I am writing a string in the notepad file such as Hello //World. Then it is printing "/" this div operator which I don't want. What actually I want is that Hello should be printed in the output and World should get commented. I know I have included the code for div operator but it is also necessary to include. Just wanted to know how I can achieve this comment logic while checking the logic for checking the div operator should also be there.

Here is the code!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        
        File newFile = new File("C:/temp/sourcecode.txt");
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(newFile);
        //Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        char ch;
        String str;
        
        
        
        while(scanFile.hasNextLine()){
        str = scanFile.nextLine();
        int l = str.length();
        if(!str.startsWith("//") && !str.startsWith("/*") && !str.endsWith("*/")) {
        for(int i =0; i<l ; i++) {
            ch = str.charAt(i);
            
            System.out.println(ch);
                
            if(ch == '*'){
                System.out.println("The Operator is MUL");
                System.out.println("arop\n");
            }
            if(ch == '/')
            {
                 System.out.println("The Operator is DIV");
                 System.out.println("arop\n");
            }
            

            
        }
        }
       
        
            int OP = 0;
            
            switch(OP){
                case 0: 
                    if(str.contains("<") && str.contains(">")){
                        System.out.println("The Operator is NE");
                        System.out.println("relop\n");
                        break;
                    }
                case 1: 
                    if(str.contains("<") && str.contains("=")){
                        System.out.println("The Operator is LE");
                        System.out.println("relop\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    
                case 2: 
                    if(str.contains(">") && str.contains("=")){
                        System.out.println("The Operator is GE");
                        System.out.println("relop\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    
                case 3: 
                    if(str.contains("<")){
                        System.out.println("The Operator is LT");
                        System.out.println("relop\n");
                        break;
                    }
                case 4: 
                    if(str.contains(">")){
                        System.out.println("The Operator is GT");
                        System.out.println("relop\n");
                        break;
                    }
                case 5: 
                    if(str.contains("==")){
                        System.out.println("The Operator is EQ");
                        System.out.println("relop\n");
                        break;
                    }
                case 6: 
                    if(str.contains("+")){
                        System.out.println("The Operator is ADD");
                        System.out.println("arop\n");
                        break;
                    }
                case 7: 
                    if(str.contains("-")){
                        System.out.println("The Operator is SUB");
                        System.out.println("arop\n");
                        break;
                    }
//                case 8: 
//                    if(str.contains("*")){
//                        System.out.println("The Operator is MUL");
//                        System.out.println("arop\n");
//                        break;
//                    }
//                case 9: 
//                    if(str.contains("/")){
//                        System.out.println("The Operator is DIV");
//                        System.out.println("arop\n");
//                        break;
//                    }
                case 10: 
                    if(str.contains("=")){
                        System.out.println("The Operator is ASN");
                        System.out.println("otop\n");
                        break;
                    }
                case 11: 
                    if(str.contains("'")){
                        System.out.println("The Operator is PRN");
                        System.out.println("otop\n");
                        break;
                    }
                case 12: 
                    if(str.contains(";")){
                        System.out.println("The Operator is LTRN");
                        System.out.println("otop\n");
                        break;
                    }
                case 13: 
                    if(str.contains("{")){
                        System.out.println("The Operator is LBRC");
                        System.out.println("otop\n");
                        break;
                    }
                case 14: 
                    if(str.contains("}")){
                        System.out.println("The Operator is RBRC");
                        System.out.println("otop\n");
                        break;
                    }      
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You  can't use `startsWith()` in this case because the comment can, as you see, start in the middle and not only at the beginning of the line.

Comment: You won't get very far with this approach. Scanning the entire line for individual operators won't work unless the language is severely restricted (basically allowing only one operator per line.)

Comment: @GuyIncognito I don't think "getting very far" is the point. The OP is still learning, and they probably just want to build a "severely restricted" language as a starter. And perhaps, after seeing how restricted this approach is, understand more deeply the advantages of other approaches.

Comment: Good points, although I highly doubt that.

Comment: @Progman Okay but isn't there is something like `startBetween` function, i am just asking that something exists in java so that i can achieve my desire result

Answer (score 2):

When programming a compiler the different input words in your code are called tokens, and the phase of recognising the role of each token is called the lexical analysis phase.

When trying to recognise tokens usually what is used is regex which is a way of implementing a finite automata.

You can read about it in much more detail here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis

You should replace the usage of contains, and use a lexer, it's the name of the tool that does lexical analysis. It uses regexes because it's not just about `/` and `//`, there can be many different situations where your compiler will need to decide which token to choose.

Here's an example of a finite automate for recognising different tokens, notice that for each prefix there can be many options for possible tokens:

[image]

In Java you can use jflex which will generate lexer code with your tokens definitions.

Answer (score 0):

When you find a `/`, you need to check the *next* character.

```java
if (ch == '/') {
    char nextCh = (i + 1 < l ? str.charAt(i + 1) : '\0');
    if (nextCh == '/') {
        System.out.println("The Operator is EndOfLineComment");
        System.out.println("arop\n");
        i++;
    } else if (nextCh == '*') {
        System.out.println("The Operator is TraditionalComment");
        System.out.println("arop\n");
        i++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("The Operator is DIV");
        System.out.println("arop\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes its seems good but i dont want to print something like its comment or not just want the compiler to ignore that string starting from // or /*, so how can i achieve this?

Comment: @SameoVoran For `//`, don't print anything and `break` out of the `for` loop. For `/*`, set a flag marking parser as `inComment`, then as it progresses, it should only look for `*/`, silently skipping every thing else. Using a flag allows you existing line processing logic to handle when `/* */` comment crosses multiple lines.

Comment: For me its difficult to understand like this way, can you tell me all this with a code?

Comment: @SameoVoran I really don't think you should do it this way. If you're working on a complete compiler you're going to tackle many more cases just like this `/` case. What you're actually doing in your code and in this code example above is implementing a regex.